# Jquery slide menu x-scroll issue

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html

I have built a custom slide menu which is giving me a slight bit of grief. [Click here for example](http://www.dgimanagement.com/index.php/pop-up/music-pop-copy/rev-run#) when you click the menu button, the slide menu pushes the background image to the right and leaves and excess of x-scroll.

My objective for this function is to have sliding menu to sit on top of background image. Currently my background image is an `<img>` tag and is `absolute` positioned as the clients wants to update images manually. this maybe the main reason why this issue is occurring. Also the `div id="right"` is wrapping all the content, including the background image. I have trying placing around with where i wrap the content however i can't figure out a method to make this work correctly i am wondering if there is a way to to work around this  Below is a snippet of code, both javascript and HTML structure.

```
$('#button').toggle( 
function() {
    $('#right').animate({ left: 400 }, 'slow', function() {
        $('#button').html('Close');
    });
}, 
function() {
    $('#right').animate({ left: 0 }, 'slow', function() {
        $('#button').html('Menu');
    });
}
```

);

```
<div id="right">
    <div id="menubar">
        <div id="button">
            Menu
        </div>
    </div>

<div id="menu">
    <ul>
        <li><a href="#">Menu Item 1</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Menu Item 2</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Menu Item 3</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Menu Item 4</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Menu Item 5</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Menu Item 6</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Menu Item 7</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Menu Item 8</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Menu Item 9</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Menu Item 10</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Menu Item 11</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Menu Item 12</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

can someone advise me on a way i can solve this issue?

Comment: Use `body{overflow-x:hidden;}` to get rid of the scroll.

Comment: Will post it as an answer then.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simpy add :

```
Body{
    overflow-x:hidden;
}
```

So hide the **body**-s horizontal scroll.

More information about [owerflow](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/CSS/overflow).